# Нужно взять дату из базы данных SQL и сравнить ее с сегодняшней

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, дата

Пробовал сам, но сравнивает лишь по дню:

```
q = datetime.datetime.now()
b = str(q.day) +'-'+ str(q.month) +'-'+ str(q.year)
cursor.execute("SELECT po FROM blog")
t_1 =  cursor.fetchall()
for i in t_1:
    if datetime.datetime.strptime(i[0],'%d-%m-%Y') < datetime.datetime.strptime(b,'%d-%m-%Y'):
        print(i)
        cursor.execute("UPDATE blog SET znsr = ?",(1,))
```

Если дата уже прошла, то нужно отдельному столбцу в БД присвоить единицу

Comment: не надо это делать на питоне. SQL сам отлично справиться. `update blog set znsr=1 where po < now()` тут now() это функция  самой СУБД в MySQL она называется именно так,  в других СУБД может называться по другому, смотрите документацию на вашу базу

Comment: cursor.execute("UPDATE blog SET znsr=1 WHERE po < now()")
   sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: now

Comment: Значит у вас не MySQL. Посмотрите как называется функция получания текущей даты в используемой вами СУБД (которую стоит указывать в вопросе, что бы можно было получить рассчитанный именно на ваш случай ответ)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы найти записи с меньшей датой в базе данных, [можно стандартную SQL функцию `current_date` использовать](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

```sql
SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE "date" < current_date;
```

К примеру, для таблицы:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "table"
    ("id" int, "date" date)
;

INSERT INTO "table"
    ("id", "date")
VALUES
    (1, '2018-04-27'),
    (2, '2018-04-28'),
    (3, '2018-04-29')
;
```

[Результат select запроса](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7bc04/1/0):

```sql
id date
1  2018-04-27
```

Comment: cursor.execute("UPDATE blog SET znsr=1 WHERE po < current_date")
Все равно не работает. Дата 29-3-2016 не проходит, ее значение не меняется

Comment: @Трофим видите ссылку на sql fiddle в ответе? Попробуйте создать похожий *минимальный* но полный пример sql, который демонстрирует проблему (ввод, запрос, вывод). Явно опишите чем полученный вывод от желаемого отличается. Обновите  ваш вопрос.